# Taylor series approximation for $(x^{2}+(1-x)^{2})^{y} - (1 - x)^{2y}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, taylor-expansion

It is said $1-(1-x)^y \approx yx$

Assuming $yx<<1$ and using Taylor series approximation.

$x$ can be $10^{-15}$ and $y$ can be $10^{9}$ so $yx<<1$

My question is can we simplify

$(x^{2}+(1-x)^{2})^{y} - (1 - x)^{2y}$ to something similar to $yx^{2}$

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The multivariate form of the Taylor expansion is given as the 4th equation [here](http://www.math.ucdenver.edu/~esulliva/Calculus3/Taylor.pdf). You will need to use partial derivatives but you can derive a similar formula to what you want.

Comment: You would need to specify the $x$ and $y$ co-ordinates of the point you're taking the expansion from.

Comment: The algebra is nightmarish so, unless you're Ramanujan's ghost or want to waste an evening, I wouldn't attempt it without some calculus software. I get an answer very similar to yours for the polynomial up to $3$ terms about $(0,0)$: $f\approx kyx^2$ for a constant that I'm sure you can find. Best of luck

Comment: Are you looking for a Taylor series in x with parameter y or a Taylor series in both variables?

Comment: herb_steinberg raises a good point; my previous comments were for a series in both variables and should not be used if $y$ is a parameter.

Comment: Thanks for comments, @herb_steinberg and Jam. I am looking for Taylor series in both variables.

Comment: In one article I encountered $1−(1−)^ \approx $ in which it says it was derived with Taylor series approximation with assumption that xy<<1.       But I have no idea how they simplified it to xy.    And I want to simplify $(^2+(1−)^2)^−(1−)^{2}$